# Spring Amqp - Dynamically Disable/Enable RabbitListener while DB Batch running

Tags: spring-amqp

We have the scenario where messages are pulled off of an Amqp Queue and written to our DB - However, during scheduled DB batch runs the DB is unavailable and we're unable to write and so we would like messages to remain on the queue during these windows.

I'm trying to ascertain the best way to deal with this - simply throw an exception in the @RabbitListener method to (repeatedly) re-queue the messages or using a Spring scheduler attempt to stop/start the listener (I see that the SimpleMessageListenerContainer has stop/start methods).

Any suggestions as to the best (or better) approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to take into account is a reply capabilities on the listener.

See an `AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Set a {@link RetryTemplate} to use when sending replies; added to each message
 * listener adapter.
 * @param retryTemplate the template.
 * @since 2.0.6
 * @see #setReplyRecoveryCallback(RecoveryCallback)
 * @see AbstractAdaptableMessageListener#setRetryTemplate(RetryTemplate)
 */
public void setRetryTemplate(RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
    this.retryTemplate = retryTemplate;
}

/**
 * Set a {@link RecoveryCallback} to invoke when retries are exhausted. Added to each
 * message listener adapter. Only used if a {@link #setRetryTemplate(RetryTemplate)
 * retryTemplate} is provided.
 * @param recoveryCallback the recovery callback.
 * @since 2.0.6
 * @see #setRetryTemplate(RetryTemplate)
 * @see AbstractAdaptableMessageListener#setRecoveryCallback(RecoveryCallback)
 */
public void setReplyRecoveryCallback(RecoveryCallback<?> recoveryCallback) {
    this.recoveryCallback = recoveryCallback;
}
```

And you are right: you can use `start()/stop()` as well.
For this reason you need to get injected a `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean and use its:

```
/**
 * Return the {@link MessageListenerContainer} with the specified id or
 * {@code null} if no such container exists.
 * @param id the id of the container
 * @return the container or {@code null} if no container with that id exists
 * @see RabbitListenerEndpoint#getId()
 * @see #getListenerContainerIds()
 */
public MessageListenerContainer getListenerContainer(String id) {
```

To get access to an appropriate listener container for your `@RabbitListener` and `stop()` or `start()` it according your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your help Artem - yet to implement it, but it looks like the stop/start route aligns more closely with what we need to do.